Checking Svarc-Milnor Lemma
Let $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ act by matrix multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I want to check what conditions are satisfied and not satisfied of the Svarc-Milnor Lemma:
(Svarc-Milnor Lemma): If $G$ acts in a proper geodesic metric space $X$, and the action is proper and cocompact, then $G$ is finitely generated and the map $\phi:G\longrightarrow X$ is a quasi-isometry.
I think that the action of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not proper, because if you take $S^1$ as a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & n \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ maps $(1,0)$ in $(1,0)$, so the set $\{M\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z}):MS^1\cap S^1\neq\emptyset\}$ is infinite and the action is not proper.
But for checking if the action is cocompact i don't have any idea how to attack that problem, beacuse i don't how the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^{2}/SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ looks. Any help will be appreciated. By the way this is 5.E.14 exercise of Clara Löh Geometric Group Theory book.

You (or Loh) misspelled Schwarz' name, see here. As a hint, consider the orbit of the unit square with one vertex at the origin.

I now see that $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, moving the plane to the right if $y>0$, to the left if $y<0$ and the $x$-axis stay fixed, and a $°90$ counterclockwise rotation. I also note that lines that pass through the origin go to lines that pass through the origin, but i don't know how to conclude. @MoisheKohan

Did you also notice other shearing transformations that it contains? What happens if you apply these to the given point in the plane? Can you move it closer to the unit square?

All the horizontal lines are stay fixed by the shearing matrices, and by the $90°$ rotation, I think all the horizontal lines are identified in the quotient, but also horizontal lines are identified with the vertical $y$ axis and this axis is identified with all oblique lines with slope $1/m$, so maybe the quotient is the real projective line $\mathbb{RP}^{1}$? if not, you can put an answer, so i can understand better. @MoisheKohan

What is special about horizontal lines? Do you know that you can shear in other directions?

I do not understand what you wrote.

I see that the orbit of the unit square covers all the strip $(-\infty,\infty)\times[0,1]$, so in the quotient if we collapse this to a point, we get something like $\mathbb{R}\vee\mathbb{R}$, right? Maybe that's the final space...?

I know what a $G$-orbit is, I do not know what an orbit is.

The linear action of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ is not cocompact, in the following sense: if $C \subset \mathbb R^2$ is a compact subset then
$$\bigcup_{M \in SL(2,\mathbb Z)} MC \ne \mathbb R^2
$$
For the proof, choose a radius $r$ such that $C$ is contained in the ball of radius $r$ around the origin. Then choose a natural number $k > r$.
Consider any integer lattice point $(m,n) \ne (0,0) \in \mathbb Z^2$.
Notice that $(m,n)$ has norm $\ge 1$, and therefore the lattice point $k \cdot (m,n) = (km,kn)$ has norm $>r$. It follows that $(km,kn) \not\in C$.
But the action of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ leaves $\mathbb Z^2$ invariant and preserves scalar multiplication. Therefore, for every $M \in SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, if we apply the previous paragraph to $(m',n') = M^{-1}(m,n)$ it follows that $(km',kn') \not\in C$, and so $(km,kn) \not\in MC$.
This proves that $(km,kn) \not\in \bigcup_{M \in SL(2,\mathbb Z)} MC$.
As a particular example, $(k,0) = k(1,0) \not\in \bigcup_{M \in SL(2,\mathbb Z)} MC$.

I'll remark also that for your example, cocompactness in the sense that I have used is equivalent to the statement that the quotient space is compact, using the fact that the phase space $\mathbb R^2$ of the action is locally compact. For a proof see this MathOverflow answer.
